# Getting error The defined artifact is not an archetype on creating project in eclipse (Mac OS)

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a new project from maven for spring mvc developement but getting this error

```
Unable to create project from archetype [co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2 -> http://maven-repository.com/artifact/co.ntier/spring-mvc-archetype/1.0.2]
The defined artifact is not an archetype
```

Getting this error for every archetype I am trying to import on eclipse neon2.0

Comment: Your configuration seemed to be wrong, cause `http://maven-repository.com/artifact/co.ntier/` this is no maven repsository which you can use to consume artifacts...

Comment: I can see it when I open the link I see aftifact defined